# Cannot add my own domain to google api notification endpoint

Tags: push-notification, google-drive-api, google-search-console

I'm trying to use [Google Push Notification](https://developers.google.com/drive/push). I've followed [the registering process listed here](https://developers.google.com/drive/push#registering), in short, my domain **is verified in https** in Google Webmaster Tools.

But, when I try to **add a notification endpoint** in Google Cloud Console, I get the following error: `You do not have access to the following domain: https://mydomain.com:8000/` *(where mydomain is replaced accordingly).*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webmaster tools require a complete URL, say `https://mydomain.com:8000` where Cloud Console only needs the domain `mydomain.com` without protocol or port (and won't work if given).