# Can't add domain for push notifications in google developers console

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-apps

I've created a new application in google developers console, my app is using the Google Calendar API and I want to be able to get push notifications on changes in the calendar. I've added and verified my domain in Web Master Tools, when I try to add the domain in the push notifications section in the console I get an error:

> Error
>
> You do not have access to the following domain: ***

I tried to do that with another application (with different google account), and I encounter the same problem, It seems like google are having a problem because it's not the first time I'm doing it and it should be pretty simple, any suggestions?

Comment: have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219292/cannot-add-my-own-domain-to-google-api-notification-endpoint yet?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In order to add a domain to the "Push notifications" you must verify your domain in webmaster tools with a "https://" prefix, otherwise it won't work because push notifications in Google works only with "https://", that's why you need to verify it in webmaster tools with "https://" so Google can verify you have an SSL.

Comment: Geez, wish they would just state that in their documentation. At least it wasn't obvious to me.

Answer (score 0):

This will be helpful incase if you are using subdomains.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35163?hl=en&ref_topic=4564314&vid=1-635796479292102918-3720802661

When you verify that you own a domain (such as example.com using DNS verification, you've proven that you have control of the domain, all its subdomains, and all sites in those subdomains.

Similarly, if you have verified http://www.example.com (using any verification method), and then add http://www.example.com/test, you will be automatically verified as an owner of http://www.example.com/test. You'll remain a verified owner of the subdirectory even if you later delete http://www.example.com from your Search Console account.