# Unable to see domains in google developer console

Tags: push-notification, google-drive-api, google-developers-console

I have registered and verified some domains in google dev console. They are verified in webmaster. But somehow, when I go to dev console, I am unable to see any domains. I have refreshed the page multiple times, since 24 hours, tried on incognito but not able to see any domains. Please find below the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the dev console requires only the `mydom.com` and webmaster requires `https://mydom.com` This SO answer helped me: [Cannot add my own domain to google api notification endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219292/cannot-add-my-own-domain-to-google-api-notification-endpoint?rq=1)

I was adding `https://mydom.com` in google dev console for some endpoints which was then when domain list was empty.

Answer (score 1):

Based from [Google Apps Administrator Help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1071480?hl=en), an issue wherein after completing the steps to verify domain ownership, you may receive an error indicating domain verification failed. Common reasons for this error are:

- Please remember it takes up to **48 hours** for the domain to be verified.
- Depending on which domain verification option you used, it's possible that the required record was not created or entered correctly. See the instructions and articles related to your selected domain verification option given in the given documentation.

Lastly, if you’ve confirmed your domain verification records are in place and your domain ownership is still not verified after 48 hours, please [contact support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213).